# AWS (GovCloud) Lambda Destination Not Triggering

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I am working in **AWS GovCloud** I have the following configuration in AWS Lambda:

1. A Lambda function which decodes a payload
2. A Kinesis Stream set as a trigger for the aforementioned function
3. A Lambda Destination (we have tried Lambda functions as well as SQS, SNS)

No matter the configuration, I cannot seem to get Lambda to trigger the destination function (or queue in the event of SQS).

Here is the current Lambda Function. I have tried many permutations of the result/return payload without avail.

```py
import base64
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    for record in event['Records']:
        payload = base64.b64decode(record['kinesis']['data']).decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
        print("Success")
        result = {
        "statusCode": 202,
        "headers": {
        #'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        "body": '{payload}'
        }
    
    return json.dumps(result)
```

I then send a message to Kinesis with the AWS CLI (I have noted that "Test" in the console does not observe desintations as per [Jared Short](https://www.trek10.com/blog/lambda-destinations-what-we-learned-the-hard-way/) ).

```
Every 0.1s: aws kinesis put-records --stream-name test-stream --records Data=SGVsbG8sIHRoaXMgaXMgYSB0ZXN0IGZyb20gdGhlIEFXUyBDTEkh,PartitionKey=partitionkey1                            Thu Jul  8 19:03:54 2021

{
    "FailedRecordCount": 0,
    "Records": [
        {
            "SequenceNumber": "49619938447946944252072058244333476686328287240252293122",
            "ShardId": "shardId-000000000000"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using Cloudwatch metrics and logs I am able to observe the function being triggered by the messages sent to Kinesis every .1 second.

[image]

The metrics charts indicate a success (as I expect).

Here is an example log from Cloudwatch:

```
START RequestId: 0cf3fb87-06e6-4e35-9de8-b30147e7be9d Version: $LATEST
Loading function
Success
END RequestId: 0cf3fb87-06e6-4e35-9de8-b30147e7be9d
REPORT RequestId: 0cf3fb87-06e6-4e35-9de8-b30147e7be9d  Duration: 1.27 ms   Billed Duration: 2 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 51 MB  Init Duration: 113.64 ms    
START RequestId: e663fa4a-2d0b-42d6-9e38-599712b71101 Version: $LATEST
Success
END RequestId: e663fa4a-2d0b-42d6-9e38-599712b71101
REPORT RequestId: e663fa4a-2d0b-42d6-9e38-599712b71101  Duration: 1.04 ms   Billed Duration: 2 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 51 MB  
START RequestId: b1373bbe-d2c6-49fb-a71f-dcedaf9210eb Version: $LATEST
Success
END RequestId: b1373bbe-d2c6-49fb-a71f-dcedaf9210eb
REPORT RequestId: b1373bbe-d2c6-49fb-a71f-dcedaf9210eb  Duration: 0.98 ms   Billed Duration: 1 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 51 MB  
START RequestId: e0382653-9c33-44d6-82a7-a82f0f416297 Version: $LATEST
Success
END RequestId: e0382653-9c33-44d6-82a7-a82f0f416297
REPORT RequestId: e0382653-9c33-44d6-82a7-a82f0f416297  Duration: 1.05 ms   Billed Duration: 2 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 51 MB  
START RequestId: f9600ef5-419f-4271-9680-7368ccc5512d Version: $LATEST
Success
```

However, viewing the cloudwatch logs/metrics for the destination lambda function or SQS queue clearly show that the destination is not being triggered.

**Over the course of troubleshooting, I have over-provisioned IAM policies to the Lambda function execution role so I am fairly confident that it is not an IAM related issue. Additionally, both functions are sharing the same execution role.**

One thing I am not clear on after reviewing AWS documentation and 3rd party information is the criteria by which AWS determines success or failure for a given function. I am currently researching the invokation docs in search of what might be wrong here - but my interpretation is that AWS knows our function is successful based on the above Cloudwatch metrics showing a 100% success rate.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or how to try to troubleshoot the destination trigger for lambda?

Edit: As pointed out, the code is not correct for multiple record events. This is a function of senseless troubleshooting/changes to the code to get the Destination to trigger. Even something as simple as this does not invoke the destination.

```
import base64
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    # for record in event['Records']:
    #     payload = base64.b64decode(record['kinesis']['data']).decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
    #     print("Success")
    #     result = {
    #     "statusCode": 202,
    #     "headers": {
    #     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    #         },
    #     "body": '{"Success":True, payload}'
    #     }

    return { "result": "OK" }
```

**So, the question: Can someone demonstrate it is possible to have a Kinesis Stream Event Source Trigger a Lambda Function which successfully triggers a Lambda destination in AWS Govcloud?**

Comment: Is your indentation correct? As written, you are overwriting `result` every record.

Comment: We are only sending one record per event for testing purposes, but you're correct, this code is not correct for multi-record events. Even if I don't actually do any message processing I cannot get Destination to work.

Comment: Are you trying to configure destination for lambda success or failure? In my understanding, for stream invocation (kinesis data stream), you can configure only SNS or SQS as destination on failure. Destination can not be configured for success

Comment: Both success and failure. If that is the case, it is not enforced by the Govcloud UI nor the CLI where we are able to use 'put-function-event-invoke-config' to set the destination.

Comment: "put-function-event-invoke-config" api is used for **asynchronous** invocation. When lambda function reads from kinesis data stream it is **synchronous** invocation [KDS-lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html)

Comment: I dont have gov-cloud region so wont be able to comment on that. You can try either [create-event-source-mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/create-event-source-mapping.html) or [update-event-source-mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-event-source-mapping.html) api to add or update KDS-lambda event source mapping. This api also shows destination for successful invocation. You can try it

Comment: Any luck on this? I am having trouble getting an Asynchronous Node.js lambda function to send anything to my destinations in Gov Cloud, both on success and failure.